# invalid opcode for this.balance when contract balance > 0

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging, remix, invalid-opcode

I get an exception when I call getBalance in Remix and the contract balance is greater than 0 (ie. I sent some ether using the fallback function):

> Exception during execution. (invalid opcode). Please debug the
>   transaction for more information.

When contract balance is 0 then getBalance correctly returns 0.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Test {

    function() payable {}

    function getBalance() public constant returns(uint bal) {
        bal = this.balance;
        return bal;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error in your code, I think after sending a transaction to your contract using the `fallback` function you call `getbalance` function with a non null value. While getbalance isn't a payable function you will get the mentioned error.
So after before calling getbalance make sure that the value is 0 in remix transaction value :

[image]

Comment: indeed, I left the value there for every attempt. How embarrassing :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. I think it is a browser cache problem.
Try refreshing the page but first copy the contract address so you can watch it later by clicking "At address" button.